# Get access tokens with react-aad-msal for two different resources and scopes

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

Developed one **React** app which needs to call two different APIs with access tokens. The application's code uses for authentication the [react-aad-msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal) library. Originally the application has built to call only one API where I have requested the necessary access token which works like charm.

As per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-permissions) about using permissions which states:

> An access token can be used only for a single resource, but encoded inside the access token is every permission that your app has been granted for that resource.

Based on that I need to request two different access tokens because *the resources are different*, that's clear.

**Working solution with only one resource and scope:**

Creating the necessary provider for `<AzureAD>` wrapper:

```
const config = {
   auth: {
      authority: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_AUTHORITY,
      clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
      redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_REDIRECT_URI
   },
   cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: true
   }
};

const authenticationParameters = {
   scopes: ['https://<our-api-name>.azurewebsites.net/user_impersonation'],
};

// saved to AuthenticationService.provider - logic removed
new MsalAuthProvider(config, authenticationParameters, LoginType.Redirect);
```

Then passing it to `<AzureAD>` wrapper:

```
<AzureAD provider={AuthenticationService.provider}
         forceLogin={true}>
```

No issues here.

**Questions:**

So I am a bit confused how should I handle the scenario if I need two access tokens from different resources and scopes.

Once I try to add to scopes array the other resource and scope as the following:

```
const authenticationParameters = {
    scopes: [
       'https://<our-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/user_impersonation',
       'https://<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<api-guid>/access_as_user'
    ],
};
```

It gives obviously the following error message:

> AADSTS28000: Provided value for the input parameter scope is not valid because it contains more than one resource.

Interested in the following:

1. How should I get the other access token properly to send to the other API?
2. Shouldn't the user will be redirected two times to login page?
3. Can the situation be handled in one request somehow?

Any clarification or idea is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hi @Norbitrial, did you manage to do it using the library? I'm having exactly the same problem. I can get the id token for the user, but then how do I get the access token for an api using this library? I managed to do it using the normal MSAL.js library, but not using this wrapper library.

Comment: @NelsonLarios I managed to working but not with 2 different resources because that's not the intention of this library I believe. As it's been suggested in the answer section I built only one so called **UX API**, an entry point and handling all the data operations in the background for different resources. I was using [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) for the API calls. At the end you will have one resource and you can create different scopes what you can manage with this library. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, @norbitrial  i hope you can read my comment, well im using the new library msal2. and its the same issue, you cant login for multiple resources, my question is, if we follow this kind of Arquitecture arent we falling on a funnel problem where all the calls will be redirected to a single point? exampple here [react-api-b2c] (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-spa-dotnetcore-webapi-obo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aside, an architecture where there are 2 levels of API is often the preferred option, though of course this is likely to be out of scope for your immediate problem:

- An entry point API is focused on serving your React app and similar consumers - this might be branded the User Experience API
- Entry point APIs call core services to do the real work - these might be the Products, Users, Stock APIs

In this setup each UI only ever needs to call a Single API and the OAuth work related to getting data from multiple sources is simpler

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I like that design what you just explained in your answer, I think I will end up having UX API as you mentioned which requires the already existing access token, in the background we can make a call to the other API.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I get the other access token properly to send to the other API?

Sadly I'm not sure how to do that in the context of that library. Usually you call acquireTokenSilent twice on the UserAgentApplication object.

> Shouldn't the user will be redirected two times to login page?

No. You specify both scopes for the login redirect. 
Then you can get two tokens silently with acquireTokenSilent with no user interaction.

> Can the situation be handled in one request somehow

See above, you need to call login once and acquireTokenSilent twice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that makes sense. Maybe that library is not capable of what I need exactly but in the same time MSAL can acquire both tokens.